# Full - Text Search Service dependency deleted (objectExplorer)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I m trying to backup a database but i get a message relating to Full- Text Search is stopped. When I try to start it I get this message

Unable to start service MSFTESQL$SQL_2K5 on server ....

Additional Information : Service Dependency Deleted(objectExplorer)

Comment: Windows 7 64bit and its MS Sql server 2005

Comment: I have installed sp2 and sp3 for sql server 2005 and the error details are   
   



at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.CheckServiceActionReturnValueSuccess(UInt32 returnValue)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.Service.Start()